# Should I authenticate/authorize static files used in authenticated pages

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, static-content

I am currently developing an angular 2 app. All server side logic is accomplished using REST API.

All the APIs which require authentication/authorization are checked for session cookies(and other stuff)

But currently there is no such restriction on static angular 2 js files.
Eg.
On a control panel page, when I use web API DELETE example.com/user/1, the request is properly authenticated and authorized before deleting the user, but the page itself is still accessible as static resource.

Although user won't be able to perform server side logic without authentication/authorization is it appropriate to deliver the static files to him?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that user should see something he isn't authorize to see, even static files..
You can use the built in 'canActivate' implementation of angular router.
Basically, Its a services that's run before your component is loaded and there you can check if user is authenticate and load the component or maybe should route him to logIn page.

You can read about it more in the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html).

Comment: Okay, and I think along with this I will have to implement a server side guard too right?

Comment: You should *always* protect yourself from unauthorized users on server side, regardless of your guards in client side. The guards in client side  are nice and handy, but as all other client protection, may be manipulate.